# Why I'm getting WA(Wrong Answer) in CMPRSS problem of codechef?

Tags: c++

I'm getting WA(Wrong Answer) in "Compress the List" problem Code(CMPRSS) of CodeChef, here is the link of the problem: **https://www.codechef.com/problems/CMPRSS**
I've checked the sample output given in the problem and also some self made test cases and It's working properly.I'm not getting what's wrong in my code

here is my approach:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> number;
int main() {

    int t;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--){

        int n;
        cin>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int temp;
            cin>>temp;
            number.push_back(temp);
        }

        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){

            int count = 0;
            int temp = i;
            while (number[temp+1]-number[temp]==1){
                temp++;
                count++;
            }

            if(count>1){

                if(i+count==n-1){
                    cout<<number[i]<<"..."<<number[i+count]<<"\n";
                } else{
                    cout<<number[i]<<"..."<<number[i+count]<<",";
                }

                i = i + count;
            }
            else{
                cout<<number[i]<<",";
            }
        }

        if(i!=n){
            cout<<number[n-1]<<"\n";
        }

        number.clear();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For those not familiar with WA, it is an abbreviation for the state of Washington in the United States.  Or it could stand for Wrong Answer.  This is why I love abbreviations, there is a many to one relationship.

Comment: Note, here: `while (number[temp+1]-number[temp]==1){ `, you could have an out-of-bound access, as you don't test that `temp < n-1`

Comment: Out of curiosity, which C++ reference did you learn to use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?  Your program would compile more efficiently with the `#include <iostream>` and `#include <vector>`.  Do you know what is inside `bits/stdc++.h`?  There could be a lot of stuff you don't need.  Search the internet for "c++ monolithic include file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to check if `number[temp+1]` exists in the part

```
while (number[temp+1]-number[temp]==1){
     temp++;
     count++;
}
```

Therefore, it *may* read beyond the array and produce wrong output.
Try this case:

```
2
5
1 2 3 4 5
3
1 2 3
```

The part should be like this:

```
while (temp+1 < static_cast<int>(number.size()) && number[temp+1]-number[temp]==1){
     temp++;
     count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is partially correct because you forgot to check the upper limit index of vector: Please check the missing code in the bold letter or between ** code **:

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector number;
int main() {

```
int t;
cin>>t;

while(t--){

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int temp;
        cin>>temp;
        number.push_back(temp);
    }

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){

        int count = 0;
        int temp = i;
        while (**temp+1<n &&** number[temp+1]-number[temp]==1){
            temp++;
            count++;
        }

        if(count>1){

            if(i+count==n-1){
                cout<<number[i]<<"..."<<number[i+count]<<"\n";
            } else{
                cout<<number[i]<<"..."<<number[i+count]<<",";
            }

            i = i + count;
        }
        else{
            cout<<number[i]<<",";
        }
    }

    if(i!=n){
        cout<<number[n-1]<<"\n";
    }

    number.clear();
}


return 0;
```

}

Check my [solution](https://www.codechef.com/submit/CMPRSS).